# How to optimize a table lookup

Tags: perl, optimization

My Perl script parses a file like this:

```
    chr   start   end   strand
    chr1  11870 11891   +
    chr1  28537 28558   +
    chr1  46502 46523   +
    chr1  39909 39930   -
    chr1  43896 43917   -
    chr2  62774 62795   -
```

When `strand` is `+` it keeps the `start` and searches all the `end` of records with a `strand` `-` to pair up start and end values.

The result is like this:

```
    11870   39930
    11870   43917
    28537   39930
    28537   43917
```

To do this, I make two tables. I make a table with all the `start` of `+ strand` and another one with all the `end` of `- strand`. Then, for each `start` in my table of `start position` I search the `end` (in the table `end position`) which is bigger than my `start`.

My issue is that it takes too much time and I try to think about something which do not need to make two tables or with a "dynamic table".

Do you have an idea to search without these two tables?

#### The script:

```
##################
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Bio::SeqIO;
use Data::Dumper;

open C, "<$ARGV[0]" or die "Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier";

my ( @pair_start, @pair_end );

while ( my $ligne = <C> ) {
    
    chomp $ligne;
    my @tab = ( split /\t/, $ligne );

    while ( $tab[0] =~ m/chr[0-9]/gi ) {

        my $chr    = $tab[0];
        my $start  = $tab[1];
        my $end    = $tab[2];
        my $strand = $tab[3];

        if ( $strand eq "+" ) {
            push @pair_start, $start;
        }
        elsif ( $strand eq "-" ) {
            push @pair_end, $end;
        }
    }
}

my $seqio_obj = Bio::SeqIO->new(
    -file   => "$ARGV[1]",
    -format => "fasta"
);

my $cpt_seq = 0;
my $seq_obj = $seqio_obj->next_seq;

foreach my $pair_start ( @pair_start ) {

    foreach my $pair_end ( @pair_end ) {

        if ( $pair_start < $pair_end ) {

            my $sous_seq = $seq_obj->subseq( $pair_start, $pair_end );
            my $length = length( $sous_seq );

            if ( $length > 43 && $length < 4000 ) {
                $cpt_seq++;
            }
        }
    }
}

print "il y a $cpt_seq séquences\n";
```

Comment: We cannot help you optimize code we cannot see. Please [edit] your question and include your code. Also tell us how large the input files are. You might want to look into [Devel::NYTProf](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::NYTProf), which is a powerful profiling tool for Perl. It will tell you what parts of your program are inefficient.

Comment: Also, try searching SO for a solution, I've replied to several similar questions already over the years.

Comment: I added the script, I tried to search solution before posted @choroba but I did not find something relevant. Otherwise, there are 2.10^6 lines.

Comment: Have you thought of using a hash instead of an array?

Comment: Yes, I tried it but I think it is not the kind of structure but to use a data structure like an array or a hash.

Comment: I'm not a bioinformatician, so I don't understand how the pairing works. Do you really need to search all the possible ends, including the ones for different `chr`?

Comment: What is `if ( $length>43 && $length < 4000 ) { ... }` for?

Comment: Choroba, I do not want to search the ones for different `chr`. Borodin, this line is because I do not want to keep positions which are separate by more than 4000 and less than 43.

Comment: @Leelouh: Okay, well I think my solution should work except for that. You didn't specify it in your question so I didn't implement it, although I did separate the chromosomes, which you didn't code for. I think you should be able to work from there.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear, but I think this is what you mean. I assume you want to compare subsequences only within the same chromosome

This code works by storing a hash of arrays which contain a list of the `start` or `end` values together with the `strand` indicator for each chromosome. Then each list is sorted by position, so that we're looking for all the `end` positions after each `start` position in the list

The two `for` loops just print the required information for each chromosome

This program expects the path to the input file on the command line, and writes the output to STDOUT

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my ( %data, @chr);

while ( <> ) {
    my ( $chr, $start, $end, $strand ) = split;
    next if $start =~ /\D/;

    push @chr, $chr unless $data{$chr};

    push @{ $data{$chr} }, $strand eq '+' ? [ $start, $strand ] : [ $end, $strand ];
}

for my $chr ( @chr ) {

    my $data = $data{$chr};

    @$data = sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } @$data;

    for my $i ( 0 .. $#$data ) {
        next unless $data->[$i][1] eq '+';

        for my $j ( $i + 1 .. $#$data ) {
            next unless $data->[$j][1] eq '-';

            print join( ' ', $chr, $data->[$i][0], $data->[$j][0]), "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

#### output

```
chr1 11870 39930
chr1 11870 43917
chr1 28537 39930
chr1 28537 43917
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Borodin, it is working but I am sorry, I do not understand everything. 

Do you think you can explain this : `$strand eq '+' ? [ $start, $strand ] : [ $end, $strand ];`

It is look like something like : if $strand eq '+', keep $start, ifelse $strand eq '-', keep $end. It is correct ?

I have a question about the for loop. What $#$data is...?

Thank you very much.

Comment: @Leelouh: The list of data for each element consists of a series of two-element arrays. If the current strand is a `+` strand then it keeps the start and the strand type, otherwise it keeps the end and the strand type. According to your algorithm there's no need to keep the rest of the data. Then each list is sorted so that we're only interested in `-` strands that appear *after* each `+` strand. `$data` is a *reference* to an array, so `$#$data` is the index of the *last element* of the array `@$data`. Unless you mess with Perl, that's one less than the number of elements in the array.

Comment: @Leelouh: I suggest that you install `Data::Dump` (`cpan Data::Dump` should do it) and take a look at the hash `%data` that is constructed (`use Data::Dump` and `dd \%data`). If you can't install modules then you can make do with `Data::Dumper` (`use Data::Dumper` and `print Dumper \%data`) but the output is much less nice to read.

Comment: @Leelouh: I also suggest that you avoid using `Bio::SeqIO` if it's there only to calculate the length of the sequence, which is just `$end - $start + 1`. It will take a lot of time building and interrogating the object for such a simple calculation.